# Is it normal to only hear the music and not the audio from the microphones as well, when plugging in headphones to a mixer?

Tags: mixing

I recently bought a “SubZero SZ-MIX08USB 8-Channel USB Mixer“ after using it a few times I thought I’d try out the headphone port but you can only hear the music through them and not the vocals from the microphones aswell. I’m very new to mixers so don’t know if this is normal or if I’ve done something wrong.

Any advice would be welcome. Thank you

Comment: No, that's not normal. You do hear the microphones through the regular output channels?

Comment: The audio comes through perfectly out the speakers, music and vocals.